# How to delete text without removing parent tag ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I want to delete text without removing the parent tag in ckeditor

Examples :

`<span class="qno" data-name="qno">1</span`>

when I delete the 1 inside span the whole span was deleted. but i need that span and I can type inside the span.

Comment: can you share your code? and tell us what you expect?

Comment: Please see the above mention span tag like I have
 <span class="qno">1</span>
 <span class="qno">2</span>
 <span class="qno">3</span>
when i delete "2" inside the qno span the ckeditor delete the whole tag the output become empty . but i need like this
<span class="qno"> </span>

Comment: in `ckEditor` open the source tab and then delete only the text and then switch to text mode. check this https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/htmlformatting.html

Comment: see i need to do in programmatically so you have any ideas?

Comment: if through code you are able to access the `HTML` data (You should be) and if the class for this element is fixed and only one then use the `XPATH` to locate the element and then use `string functions` to `replace` that with blank string..you can as well use the `RegEx` to locate and replace.

Comment: In ckeditor if we have any easiest way?